# list of xy points to draw lines in python

Tags: python, list, pygame, draw

So I have a list of xy coordinates that are seperated into several sublist and I want to draw a series of lines with these coordinates:

```
points = [[-2026, 405], [-2026, 404]], 
         [[-2000, 379]],
         [[-1112, 379], [-1112, 378]]
```

I have tried using:

```
pygame.draw.lines(screen, white, False, points, 5)
```

however I get an error:

```
ValueError: points argument must contain more than 1 points
```

I believe it is because of the point `[[-2000, 379]]` because `draw.lines` requires two points and that only contains one.
Is there a way i can either use draw.line instead of draw.lines to draw my points? Or is their a way that I can have my draw function redraw the point'[[-2000, 379]]' so the my error disapppears.

And note: I want to draw the lines from the points without changing the format of my sublists because I need them all seperated from each other so i this case i have 3 sublists of xy cooridinates to draw

Comment: What is the question? Do you expect to draw a line given 1 point? It won't work. The sample with your points is also meaningless as you have two points with same coordinates and line will be of 0 length... Clarify please.

Comment: or you want to line up any two points?

Comment: sorry about the point list i mistyped them.  and i updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you `points` to this:

```
In [36]: list(itertools.chain(itertools.chain.from_iterable(points)))
Out[36]: [[-2026, 405], [-2026, 405], [-2000, 379], [-1112, 379], [-1112, 379]]
```